Understanding how thermal values are represented from a FLIR A65 Camera using Pleora eBUS SDK
My project uses a FLIR A65 thermal camera and the eBUS SDK for gigE interfacing. The frontend is in QtQuick. The core functionality is to stream from the camera and extract thermal values.
My program is successfully streaming with pixel type Mono8 (8-bit grayscale). This is what the documentation for the FLIR A65 camera says about converting pixel values to temperature in Kelvin:
"Temperature (in Kelvin) = B / log(R / (S - O) + F), where S is the 14-bit digital signal
value. log(x) is the base-e logarithm of the x parameter."
The values B, R, O, and F are Planck constants
I am concerned that my thermal values will be off because I am streaming in Mono8 rather than Mono14.
I'm currently restricted to Mono8 because QImage from Qt only supports Mono8 (Grayscale8) and Mono16 (Grayscale16).

It seems that you shouldn't have any problem as long as you take the raw data you get from the camera, without converting it to image. Note, though, that if you're actually receiving 14-bit data, it means that the image won't be accurate, since the docs explain (page 9) that they use a different bit alignment (Mono16 uses MSB, Mono14 LSB). OTOH, if you're actually receiving a Mono16 (I've not read the whole doc, but it seems it's configurable) then you must convert the value, possibly shifting it by 2 places.
